# Installing VLC on Lubuntu (Utopic Unicorn)

Tags: terminal, vlc, apt-get, ubuntu

I am having some issues installing VLC on Lubuntu (ubuntu) 14.10:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The command returns:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 vlc : Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but 2.2.0+ppa3.2 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-notify (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but 2.2.0+ppa3.2 is to be installed
       Recommends: vlc-plugin-samba (= 2.2.0-0ubuntu0.14.10.1) but 2.2.0+ppa3.2 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried to install both the packages it recommends (they are already installed apparently).

I have also followed this guide as some was having a similar problem: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2250015
and installed the xorg ppa to no avail.

Can someone please shed some light on this for me?

Many thanks!

Ed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the usual

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

apt-get should install the correct dependency versions now.

Btw why not post this on https://askubuntu.com/ ?

Comment: This solved the problem dependency problem, ty. & I don't have an account on ask ubuntu